Pressing enter for new line deletes the previously selected text in draft js
I have one issue in my custom editor using draftjs for my react app:
i have 3 words, if i select and deselect the third word and press enter, the third word got deleted. The expected behavior is it should make new line, but not deleting the third word.
here's some part of my code:
const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(
    EditorState.createEmpty(decorator)
  );
const handleEditorChange = (newEditorState: EditorState) => {
    setEditorState(newEditorState);
  };
const handleKeyCommand = (
    command: string,
    editorState: EditorState
  ): DraftHandleValue => {
    const newState = RichUtils.handleKeyCommand(editorState, command);

    if (newState) {
      setEditorState(newState);
      return "handled";
    }

    return "not-handled";
  };
<Editor
  editorState={editorState}
  onChange={handleEditorChange}
  handleKeyCommand={handleKeyCommand}
  blockStyleFn={blockStyleFn}
  placeholder={placeholder}
/>

